# Binding textblock value doesn't change after changing binded value

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, uwp, xbind

Why does TextBlock "T1" not show "101" after clicking on Button "B1" and still shows "100"?

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Name="T1" Text="{x:Bind value, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    <Button Name="B1" Content="+1" Click="B1_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public int value;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        value = 100; // initial value
    }
    private void B1_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        value = value + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `value` is a field, yes it works with `x:Bind`. Actually it should even work being `private`.

But in order for the UI to **update** the value of `value`, you need to make *one* of the three changes below -

1. Call `Bindings.Update()` after setting it.
2. change it to a [dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/custom-dependency-properties).
3. Change it to a normal property but implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your page and raise property changed event on the setter. You can read more from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged).

---

But which one to pick? This is normally what I do -

1. If the property rarely changes, I use `Bindings.Update()` and remove `Mode=OneWay` from the binding to have the best performance.
2. If the property lives in the code-behind of a UI element (like in your case), I go with a dependency property.
3. If the property lives inside a ViewModel, I use `INPC`.

Comment: Worth noting Bindings.Update() will update all x:Bind bindings on a page, so might not be the right path if your layout starts getting more complicated.

Comment: Magnificent, Thanks.